# copy multiple lines and past in the end of another text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have a bash script, which shows some flag (some text) on terminal at the end of the execution. I want to copy these flags (text) in the end of another file.

[image: end of bash script]

I want to copy these flag (**after the run of script**) in arch.make file.

Comment: Please try to avoid screenshots and paste text instead.

Comment: What is your issue with this? You could just select the output from the terminal, open your `arch.make` in an editor file, and paste tho copied lines in at the bottom.

Comment: i want copy these flag with shell script

Comment: can i  modify this script to copy last flag into another files.

Comment: You are looking for the `>>` output redirector. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207573/how-to-append-output-to-the-end-of-a-text-file

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the script, you can make it append the output to another file automatically.

Just add a `{` on a line by itself before the second `echo`, and then `} >>arch.make` after the last `echo`:

```
#echo "Please add ..."
{
echo ""
echo "INCFLAGS ..."
# etc.
echo "FPPFLAGS ..."
echo ""
} >>arch.make
```

Running that would add the result of the `echo` command within `{ ... }` to the end of the file `arch.make` each time you run the script.

Answer (score 0):

Copy sound ambiguously. In this case, it seems you want to get a output from a script and another command and append to a file (not copy the content of a file to another, right?). What you need is redirect the output to a file The basic syntax is:

> command --options arguments >> file.txt

but, if you have several commands to run, you could create a group command (a type of compound command; see **man bash**). Doing so, you get something like

> { command1 --options1 arguments1 ; command2 --options2 arguments2, ... } >> file.txt

You could use **(** **)** instead of **{** **}** for embracing the list of commands (what creates a subshell (if this doesn't make sense to you, read about envoirament im **man bash**).

Finally, if you do want both output towards the screen (or other place)  and into the file, use the program **tee**.

I hope I have helped you.

**PS:**the command mentioned above could be a script, of course.